# How to provide KafkaSource SSL files to Flink worker nodes

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am creating a Kafka-based Flink streaming application, and am trying to create an associated `KafkaSource` connector in order to read Kafka data.

For example:

```
final KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
     // standard source builder setters
     // ...
     .setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "truststore.jks")
     .build();
```

The `truststore.jks` file is created locally **on** the job manager node before the application is executed, and I've verified that it exists and is correctly populated. My problem is that, in a distributed Flink application, this `truststore.jks` does not automatically also exist on the task worker nodes, so the above code results in a `FileNotFoundException` when executed.

What I've tried:

- Use `env.registerCacheFile` and `getRuntimeContext().getDistributedCache().getFile()` in order to distribute the file to all nodes, but since the graph is being built and the application is not yet running, the RuntimeContext is not available at this stage.
- Supply a base64 parameter representation of the truststore, and manually convert it to .jks format. I'd need some sort of "pre-initialization" `KafkaSource` hook to do this, and haven't found any such functionality in the docs.
- Use an external data store, such as s3, and retrieve the file from there. As far as I can tell, the internal Kafka consumer does not support non-local filesystems, so I'd still need some pre-initialization way to retrieve the file locally on each task node.

---

What is the best way to make this file available to task worker nodes during the source initialization?

I have read similar questions posted here before:

1. [how to distribute files to worker nodes in apache flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991715/how-to-distribute-files-to-worker-nodes-in-apache-flink)

- As explained above, I don't have access to the `RuntimeContext` at this point in the application.

2. [Flink Kafka Connector SSL Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493563/flink-kafka-connector-ssl-support)

- This injects the truststore as a base64 encoded string parameter. I could do this, but since the internal Kafka consumer expects a file, I would have the problem of converting the parameter to .jks format before consumer initialization. I don't see a way of registering a "pre-initialization" hook for the `KafkaSource` in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

I was able to work around this issue by instead using the `ssl.truststore.certificates` configuration field. This allows me to supply a base64-encoded representation of the underlying `truststore.jks` certificate instead of a local file path.

[I also had to update my `kafka-clients` dependency to `2.7.x`+ as this configuration is not available in older versions of the library]